# How to autofill the input element that is the child of a label element with a specific aria-label?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, automation, wai-aria

```
function setInputText() {
 
  const label = document.querySelector('label[aria-label="Title"]');
  if (!label) {
   
    console.error('bleh');
    return;
  }

 
  const input = label.querySelector('input');
  if (!input) {
   
    console.error('awefawefwe');
    return;
  }


  input.value = 'test';
}

function setInputText() {
  const label = document.querySelector('label[aria-label="Title"]');
  if (!label) {
    console.error('No label element with aria-label="Title" was found');
    return;
  }

  const input = label.nextElementSibling;
  if (!input) {
    console.error('No input element was found as a child of the label element');
    return;
  }

  input.value = 'awefaweafewefaaweawefaefw';
}
```

Trying to autofill a form in Chrome using the aria-label attribute. Can't figure out why this won't work.

Comment: First snippet looks correct, can you provide html snippet? And what do you get in result of first snippet? Is it an error or one of your logs?,, second snippet tries to find input next to label but you mentioned input is a child of label so i think second one is not correct, this part i mean `label.nextElementSibling `

Comment: Could you please try to render your code interactive with a code snippet so that we can reproduce? You might realise what the issue is in doing so as well (:

Comment: `aria-label` used on a `<label>` elements seems like a misuse of that attribute. The purpose of `<label>` is to declare its text contents as the accessible name for the input. So it would be more appropriate to give the attribute to the input itself. If you need an attribute for scripting, you should [use `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).